# Get ID of executing Process/Thread in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, c++builder-2010

Let's say I have a class with the function

```
class foo 
{
  ...

  void bar() {
    OutputDebugString(........);
     // mode code
  }
}
```

Is it possible to print the ID of the current thread (or if it's the main application) that is executing the function using **OutputDebugString**?

I have a large application I'm debugging and have found a deadlock situation and would like to check which threads are included in the deadlock. Since it could possibly be the same thread that is locking it's own critical section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [`GetCurrentThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683182%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: I had tested **GetThreadId()** thinking that would return the id of the current thread. But **GetCurrentThread** and using **DuplicateHandle** on the retrieved psudeohandle worked like a charm. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GetCurrentThreadId()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683183.aspx).

Note that a thread cannot deadlock itself on a critical section.  Once a thread has obtained the lock to the critical section, it can freeing re-enter that same lock as much as it wants (same thing with a mutex).  Just make sure to unlock the critical section for each successful lock (re)entry so that OTHER threads do not become deadlocked.